# Which is preferable: Suffice to say, or Suffice it to say?

Tags: comparisons, verb-phrases

The Australian Concise Oxford Dictionary, ed 7 (1987) [which I find to be still a useful resource], says "suffice" is an intransitive verb, giving the example "suffice to do."  But it also gives the phrase "suffice it to say."  This could be an idiomatice use, but there is no notation to that effect; nevertheless it is a usage with which I feel familiar and comfortable. I am proof-reading a passage that uses the phrase "suffice to say," and I am in two minds whether to correct it or not.

Comment: What does further research say, Richard? [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/suffice-it-to-say#:~:text=phrase,only%20give%20a%20short%20explanation.) licenses both variants of the fixed phrase. While [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Suffice+to+say%2C+Suffice+it+to+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggest that the four-word variant is used 75% of the time. //  It's probably an unusual enough construction to be called an idiom.

Comment: They're both obscure and archaic variants of _It suffices to say_, which means _It is enough to say_. They're both rather formal, as archaic phrases usually are.